# 60Hz Ethernet Wave?

Tags: ethernet

I just unsheathed an Ethernet cable and probed it with a scope. What I see is an almost perfect 60Hz sine wave signal. Why is this? I can't find anything that would explain to me why this is the case.

What I expect to see at least is a modulated signal, but in this case all I see is a clean sine wave. I am continuously running a ping command on the computers connected to both ends of the Ethernet cable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ethernet is transformer isolated, so you are probably just seeing mains frequency capacitive pickup from the ambient fields.

Probe across one of the data pairs (Note that 100Mb uses only one pair in each direction), you are looking for signal at 10s of MHz.

Answer (score 2):

Ethernet is a protocol and physical layer that permits systems to communicate without sharing a ground reference, that is why the 60 cycle humming around is dominating, since the cable lacks a ground it will pick all of that up in spades. On top of that it is a differential protocol, so you will need to probe both Tx+ and Tx- (or Rx+ and Rx-) at once or use a differential probe. Probing shouldn't be a problem so long as you are probing the differential pair between two systems on the cat5 cable. The differential probing will subtract the 60Hz component.